# Corrupted writes to ext hdd because of low power?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, file-corruption, usb-2

recently I've bought a case for 2.5 HDD in order to use it as an external HDD. It has USB 3.0 interface but I've also used it with older laptop which has only USB 2.0 ports. It implicates that a HDD which expects current of 0.55A and voltage 5V will be able to draw current of maximum 0.5A. I am wondering whether this can cause corrupted writes, because HDD needs the most power for writes. The HDD seems to start properly, but I had some problems with it (logical bad sectors which has been reduced to 0 with the MHDD's help) and I am trying to investigate it and find the source of the problem. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Not sure about writes, but most power consumption occurs on initial spin-up, and on intensive seeks on a highly fragmented drives. Use a very short cable, although no guarantee, depending on your SATA drive. Better use a SSD for this purpose, or find an enclosure with expernal power supply.

Comment: It spins up without problems. In general I use these enclosures with laptop which has USB 3.0, but still this problem intrigues me.

Comment: Many external usb 2 disks used to come with a Y-shaped cable with two usb A plugs in paralled, one of which only had the power wires connected. This should allow you to get 2*500mA. They often stated you could get corrupt data if you didnt use both plugs. You can get cheap in-line usb power meters that might show you that you are drawing too much current. With thin cables the voltage will also drop.

Comment: Drawing too much current from USB 2.0? How? Isn't too small current the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I have long been using an external 2.5" HDD which also takes 5V and 0.55A. It is well-supported by USB 2.0 ports. So far, I have found no corrupted files on it.

A friend of mine told me that USB 2.0 ports can read/write and access a 0.6A hard drive just fine, and he had even been using the following 0.7A USB hard drive long before the advent of USB 3.0.

[image]